# R Programmming: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Price Each' not found

Tags: r, random-forest, training-data

R Programming:

I have a data frame called new_data

```
names(new_data)
```

```
 [1] "Order ID"         "Product"          "Quantity Ordered" "Price Each"       "Order Date"       "Purchase Address"
 [7] "Street"           "City"             "State"            "Sales"            "Month"            "Year"
```

```
#Preprocess the data:

new_data$Sales <- new_data$'Quantity Ordered' * new_data$'Price Each'
new_data$'Order Date' <- mdy(new_data$'Order Date') # Adjust based on your date format
new_data$Month <- month(new_data$'Order Date')
new_data$Year <- year(new_data$'Order Date')


#Split the data into a training set and a test set:

set.seed(123)
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(new_data$Sales, p = .7, list = FALSE, times = 1)
train_data <- new_data[splitIndex,]
test_data  <- new_data[-splitIndex,]
When I use the below code:
```

```
# Train a Multiple Linear Regression model:

lm_model <- lm(Sales ~ Month + Year + `Price Each` + `Quantity Ordered`, data = train_data)
summary(lm_model)
```

This code runs properly and fits the data in lm_model. But while training the df in a random forest as below:

```
# Train a Random Forest model:

rf_model <- randomForest(Sales ~ Month + Year + `Price Each` + `Quantity Ordered`, data = train_data, ntree = 500)

print(rf_model)
```

I got this error after running the above code:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Price Each' not found

I am trying to train the df to train the Random Forest alog and I expect to solve the error  that i am getting.

Comment: I can reproduce the error by using the iris dataset and renaming column `Species` to `Species Name`. So I'm guessing the issue is that while `lm()` is tolerant of variable names with spaces (using backticks), `randomForest()` for some reason is not. Solution: rename columns to remove spaces.

Comment: If i use single quotes to represent in the formula then another error pops up: Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in the column names seem to be causing issues with the formula syntax in R. So to resolve this, I renamed the variables to replace spaces with periods.

```
names(train_data) <- make.names(names(train_data), unique = TRUE)
names(test_data) <- make.names(names(test_data), unique = TRUE)
```

Although I was using the varaible names with periods in middle it was giving some errors:

```
Error in str2lang(termtext) : <text>:1:18: unexpected symbol
1: Month+Year+Price Each
```

So, defines another variable and used reformulate fot the formula

```
# Define the predictor variables
predictors <- c("Month", "Year", "Price.Each", "Quantity.Ordered")

# Create the formula
rf_formula <- reformulate(predictors, response="Sales")

# Train the Random Forest model
rf_model <- randomForest(rf_formula, data = train_data, ntree = 500)
print(rf_model)
```